# Changing the state of check box in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that contains 4 columns of check boxes. By default it is not possible to check or uncheck them.

How can I go about to make only one of the columns of checkboxes editable...i.o.w. not read only so that I can check or uncheck the one specific column of check box which will update the database.

Comment: Instead of asking the same question again, edit your old one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644054/making-checkbox-field-of-gridview-editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to apply enable/disable criteria on the checkboxes using row instances of grid view along with the binding data.

```
void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkBoxID");
       if(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "datasourceColumnName").ToString() == "someval")
             chk.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go to its tooltip and in itemtemplate and make the checkbox Checked=true and this may solve your problem